# Find the polynomial

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion, polynomials

We know that *f* is a polynomial with non-negative integer coefficients.

Given *f(1)* and *f(1+f(1))* return *f*. You may output *f* as a list of coefficients, an ASCII formatted polynomial, or similar.

Examples:

```
f(1)  f(1+f(1))  f
0     0          0
1     1          1
5     75         2x^2 + 3
30    3904800    4x^4 + 7x^3 + 2x^2 + 8x + 9
1     1073741824 x^30
```

Comment: Random question: I'm too tired to try to prove/disprove this right now, but is it guaranteed that we will always be able to get an answer from `f(1)` and `f(1+f(1))`?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I wouldn't have made this challenge otherwise.

Comment: Right, that is a good point. Hm. Interesting, I will look into proving that tomorrow because that's very interesting. Thanks for the interesting challenge!

Comment: The [tag:base-conversion] tag is supposed to be a hint?

Comment: As much as this is a cute puzzle, I think the code is basically base conversion. Possibly dupe?

Answer (score 27):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
‘b@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYUaSw////40N/htbGphYGBgAAA)

Returns the polynomial as a list of coefficients.

Since we know the polynomial has non-negative integer coefficients, *f(b)* can be interpreted as "the coefficients of the polynomial, taken as base *b* digits," by the definition of a base. This is subject to the condition that none of the coefficients exceeds or is equal to *b*, but we know that, because *b* is one greater than the sum of the coefficients (which is *f(1)*).

The program simply increments the first argument (`‘`) to get *1+f(1)*, then calls the base convertion atom (`b`) with the first argument as the base and the second argument as the number (using `@` to swap the order of the arguments, since `b` usually takes the number first and base second).

This was quite the clever challenge; thanks orlp!

Comment: How in the world is this possible

Comment: I need to learn jelly...

Comment: Dennis has to see this one for sure.

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, <s>29</s> 28 bytes

*Thanks to JungHwan Min for saving 1 byte! (ironically, with a `Max`)*

```
#2~IntegerDigits~Max[#+1,2]&
```

Pure function taking two nonnegative integers and returning a list of (nonnegative integer) coefficients. `#2~IntegerDigits~(#+1)` would be the same algorithm as in [Doorknob's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114469/56178); unfortunately, Mathematica's `IntegerDigits` chokes when the base equals 1, hence the need for extra bytes `Max[...,2]`.

Comment: Haha, nice one.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 38 bytes

```python
a,b=input()
while b:print b%-~a;b/=a+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@ok2SbmVdQWqKhyVWekZmTqpBkVVCUmVeikKSqW5donaRvm6ht@P@/sYGOgrGlgYmFgQEA)

---

outputs newline separated coefficients

Example output for `30, 3904800`:

```python
9
8
2
7
4
```

=> `9*x^0 + 8*x^1 + 2*x^2 + 7*x^3 + 4*x^4`

Answer (score 3):

## VBA, 75 bytes

```
Sub f(b,n)
b=b+1
Do While n>0
s=n Mod b &" " &s
n=n\b
Loop
Debug.?s
End Sub
```

When it automatically formats, it looks like this:

```
Sub f(b, n)
    b = b + 1
    Do While n > 0
        s = n Mod b & " " & s
        n = n \ b
    Loop
    Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

The `\` operator is a floor divide

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 87 bytes

```
(defun p(x y)(multiple-value-bind(q m)(floor y (1+ x))(if(= 0 q)`(,m)`(,m ,@(p x q)))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(defun find-polynomial (f<1> f<1+f<1>>)
  (multiple-value-bind (q m)
      (floor f<1+f<1>> (1+ f<1>))
    (if (zerop q) `(,m)
      (cons m (find-polynomial f<1> q)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/), 63 bytes

```
a=%1%
b=%2%
a+=1
While b>0
{s:=Mod(b,a) " "s
b:=b//a
}
Send,%s%
```

AutoHotkey assigns numbers 1-n as variable names for the incoming parameters. It causes some problems when you try to use those in functions because it thinks you mean the literal number 1 instead of the variable *named* 1. The best workaround I can find is to assign them to different variables.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 53 bytes

```
a->b->{while(b>0){System.out.println(b%-~a);b/=a+1;}}
```

Outputs a list of coefficients. Thanks to ovs for the maths.

The expression must be assigned to a `Function<Integer, IntConsumer>` and called by first `apply`ing the function, then `accept`ing the `int`. No imports are needed with Java 9's `jshell`:

```
C:\Users\daico>jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 9-ea
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> Function<Integer, IntConsumer> golf =
        a->b->{while(b>0){System.out.println(b%-~a);b/=a+1;}}
golf ==> $Lambda$14/13326370@4b9e13df

jshell> golf.apply(30).accept(3904800)
9
8
2
7
4
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 62 bytes

```
(a,b)=>{var r="";a++;while(b>0){r+=(b%a)+" ";b/=a;}return r;};
```